# JS state updates unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I am very new to JS.

Here is a page that I am working on:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import { fetchPosts, createPost } from '../actions/postActions'

import GroupedBarChart from '../containers/GroupedBarChart'

class Usage extends Component {
    state = {
        title: '',
        resp_data: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts('/en/api/usage/')
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.posts.data) {
            this.setState({resp_data: nextProps.posts.data}, function () {
                console.log(this.state.resp_data);
            });
        }
        console.log(this.state.resp_data)
    }

    render() {
        const { title, resp_data } = this.state

        return (<div>
            <GroupedBarChart
                title={ title }
                data={ resp_data }
            />
        </div>);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.posts.items,
    newPost: state.posts.item
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts, createPost })(Usage)
```

The problem with that is that the state changes unexpectedly at some point.

So in `componentWillReceiveProps` there is a `console.log` immediately after the `setState` call and the output of this console.log is exactly what I expect. However, if I print the state immediately after the if statement:

```
if (nextProps.posts.data) {
    this.setState({resp_data: nextProps.posts.data}, function () {
        console.log(this.state.resp_data);
    });
}
```

`this.state.resp_data` is an empty array.

The output of the two console.logs looks like that:

```
[] # this is outside if
(2) [{…}, {…}] # this is inside if
```

Can someone explain me why this happens and how can I overcome it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The state of this component is never set (other than you default values) in componenetDidMount() you need to setState({resp_data: responseData}) after your this.props.fetchPosts() finishes

Comment: you mean I have nextProps.posts.data correctly but state is empty?

Comment: yeah `nextProps.posts.data` is correct, then it sets the state correctly, but once it goes out of the if statement - state is empty

Comment: @VnC is this what are you trying?

if (nextProps.posts.data) {
    this.setState({resp_data: nextProps.posts.data}, function () {
        console.log(this.state.resp_data);
    });
}
console.log(this.state.resp_data); 

second console.log is not working?

Comment: yes! Then in the render `this.state.resp_data` is also empty

Comment: In here this.setState second argument is callback function which is asynch.
So you cannot see state with correct data after you call setState because your code continue and second console.log is fire before setState callback.

Comment: yeah, exactly. Just updated the question with this information. However, in the render it's still empty, though ? Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

First of get rid of `componentWillReceiveProps` method as it is not recommended to use anymore and it will be remove at version 17. You can check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) for extra information.

Secondly checkout [react lifecyles](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) so you will see your component will render with initial data at mounting phase, so I assume you have no `posts.data` at first and you fetch it at `componentDidMount`. So after you fetched data you trigger `setState` which cause another render (check lifecycle updating phase you will see setState cause render).

You call `console.log` after calling `setState` and expecting to see some data but if you look at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of it you will see it is not guarantee.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I changed the response in the back end - `data = []` to `data = {}` it has worked. I am still confused of why would that be.